# How to run 2 StreamWriters in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, streamwriter

Recently I was working on a project to write a csv file and an XML file at the same time.
They contain the same metadata information, how to open two `StreamWriter`s in C# at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean with the same *metadata*? Filename, modification date,...?

Comment: "at the same time"? Whats wrong with one then the other?

Comment: @Octopoid: well that can be useful; for instance if both xml and csv store the same format; and that it takes a long time to calculate the elements.

Comment: You can still calculate all the raw data, then convert to csv and xml, then save one then the other at the last minute, if for whatever reason you want them both to be created at a similar time.

Comment: What makes you think you *can't* open two at the same time? `var a = new StreamWriter("foo.txt"); var b = new StreamWriter("bar.txt");` - job done!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question with a trivial answer that demonstrates little understanding of the programming language/platform, and is thus unsuitable for SO.

Comment: When you say "at the same time" do you mean that they need to be written to the drive at the same instant? Or that they need be created together to avoid going through the streamwriter twice (maybe is too big)? You need to be more specific about your question.

Comment: @DanPuzey Your answer doesn't work. thx

Comment: @PedroC88 I think multi threading is the answer, because two StreamWriters can't open at the same time, which possess the same thread

Comment: @DreamTutor: in what way does my answer not work? Two `StreamWriter`s categorically *can* coexist (though possibly not if they're on the same file). How about you post some code that you think doesn't work, so we have something to go on? (Use [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and test the code I posted if you don't believe me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad so the answer is generic. In order "to write a csv file and an XML file at the same time" you have to implement sort of multi-threading, using either `Task Parallel Library` (`TPL` - recommended) or other technique available in .NET, and run the aforementioned procedures on two different threads (in either blocking or non-blocking mode).

More details on TPL implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it works for you. Please check the answer accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: Absolutely incorrect. Two `StreamWriters` can exist on the same thread; you can alternate writes to each file (which is all you'll be doing in a threaded model anyway). Implementing TPL or threading for this is a waste of time, especially since disk IO will be the bottleneck anyway.

Comment: @DanPuzey: I would disagree with that "Absolutely incorrect." statement. If you read carefully the exact question, which contains the highly-important "at the same time" condition, single thread will provide just "pseudo-parallel" execution by switching between that 2 stream-write operations, while TPL solution in possible scenario of having dual-core CPU and two Hard drives will provide true parallel execution with certain performance advantage plus non-blocking Disk IO operations (i.e. one need not to wait for another to complete). Best regards,

Comment: You've added a whole lot of extra detail that's not in the original question there: two hard drives, two cores, etc. The actual original question is "how to open two StreamWriters in C# at the same time?" The answer to that is: create two `StreamWriter`s!

Comment: @DanPuzey: The question specifically asked "how to open two StreamWriters in C# at the same time?", where "at the same time" is quite important condition (otherwise, the trivial answer could be, indeed, just to 'create 2 StreamWriters'). Therefore, in my answer I've outlined a solution which seemingly best fit the requirements, i.e. opening that StreamWriters on two different threads using TPL as an example (also, many modern PCs use dual-core and even multi-core CPU, thus use of TPL is quite justified). Best regards,

Comment: Surely you're not reading that question as "the two streamwriters must open their files simultaneously" as opposed to "the two streamwriters must both be in an open state at the same time?" The former is nigh-impossible to guarantee regardless of your use of threads and cores.

Comment: This comments thread (in addition to those aforementioned TPL multi-threads :-) is getting a bit lengthy, and the question already has been put on hold, but, anyway, thanks for the interesting discussion. Have a good day. Best regards,